# Why document.getElementById for hidden input works in IE but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

i have a problem with this part of js code not working in Chrome but working in IE.

this is my javascript code :

```
function submitformWithPage(xpage)
{

  document.getElementById('itempage').value = xpage;
 alert(xpage);
  document.searchForm.submit();

}
```

and this is my html code

```
<form name="searchForm" action="search.php" method="get">

<input  type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])) { echo $_GET['search']; } ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="test" />
<input id="item" type="hidden" name="itempage" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="pageBigForward" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="pageSmallForward" value="1" />

<button style="" onclick="javascript: submitform()">Search</button>

</form>
```

I submitted the form by using this code and it works in IE but not in Chorme.

```
<button style="" onclick="javascript: submitformWithPage(3);">3</button>
```

I am lost on how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your input has the **name** of `itempage`, not the **id**.

```
<input id="item" type="hidden" name="itempage" value="1" id="itempage"/>
```

Using names-as-ids [is only supported in IE5-7](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t10)!

Answer (score 4):

Function getElementById is searching by attribute "id", not "name".

So replace itempage with item and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use `id` instead of `name`:

```
document.getElementById('item').value = xpage;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set the name but not the ID of your hidden element to "itempage"

Answer (score 1):

It works in IE because IE considers the "name" attribute as well as the "id" attribute for "getElementById()".  It's a pretty stupid behavior, really, but it benefits your code because you don't have that string as an "id" value.